# ObjectSpace sort order

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have recently run into http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ObjectSpace.html

Is there a defined sort order?

If I call ObjectSpace.each_object(SomeClass).to_a twice in a row, am I guaranteed the same sort order?

Comment: Why would you expect any particular order?

Comment: Say I wanted to construct an directed object graph where a given node can have an arbitrary number of transitions. Say I wanted to randomize a pass through this graph using a genetic algorithm. A possible approach would be encoding this as an array of integers, where every integer signifies the transition number. This would hinge on the ObjectSpace.each_object(MyAwesomeVertex).to_a sort order being identical in both the initialization method and the fitness function

Comment: I'm not questioning the utility. There's no mention of order in the documentation so why expect there to be any particular order? I could see a GC pass rearranging the order of things behind your back especially if you're running through your graph creating and destroying objects along the way. I wouldn't depend on it even if various empirical results or analyzing the Ruby source suggested that order was maintained, a simple version change could invalidate all that.

Comment: That is a *very* dangerous use case at best. `ObjectSpace` also contains dead objects that haven't yet been garbage collected, for example. Do you really want to graph those?